# How to stop null reference exception when finding datagridview checkbox value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am using winforms and C#,.

[image]

When i try to get datagridviewcheckbox state, if the checkbox not true it shows "Null Reference Exception was caught" as Exception.

My Code is

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow fees_row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if ((bool) fees_row.Cells[0].Value == true)
    {
    }
}
```

The error is in the line:

```
if ((bool) fees_row.Cells[0].Value == true)
```

how to set datagridview checkbox value not null. or escape this exception.

Comment: Where are you writing this loop, i strongly suspect that may be selection has not got committed, can you try using `EditedFormatedValue` instead of `Value` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `DataGridViewCell` object is not `null` *first*, before trying to interrogate its value. That's what's causing the `NullReferenceException`—you're interrogating the `Value` property of a `null` object!

Change your code to look like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow fees_row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    var cell = fees_row.Cells[0];
    if (cell != null)
    {
        var value = cell.Value;
        if (value != null && (bool)value == true)
        {
            // Do whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

But before someone else leaves a snarky comment, there's generally no reason to check a Boolean value against a literal `true`. All you have to write is `if (boolValue)`

Comment: don't forget to check if `.Value!=null` (because `Value` is of type `object`)

Comment: Minor point: It may be better to do a cast with the "as" operator on cell.Value before the if statement.  Then check if it's not null and true.  That will stop any InvalidCastExceptions from being thrown.

Comment: @Corith: It might, if you had no idea what the value is or would be. But if you've designed the table and you know that its cells can only contain Boolean values, then the cast is perfectly valid. In fact, I'd say it's preferred, because if there's ever *not* a Boolean value there, you want to know about it! Throwing an exception is the right approach. But still a fair point nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (fees_row.Cells[0].Value != null)
 {
     if ((bool) fees_row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                {
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow fees_row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    var cell = fees_row.Cells[0];
    if (cell.value != null)
    {
        var value = cell.Value;
        if (value != null && (bool)value == true)
        {
            // Do whatever...
        }
    }
}
```